# Почему не работает команда `flusk run`?

Tags: flask, virtualenv

Делаю как в этом уроке: https://habr.com/ru/post/346306/

Но получаю ошибку:

```
(Web) F:\Web\WebSite>flask run

"flask" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Хотя flask установлен для этого виртуального окружения.
Причём `set FLASK_APP=main.py` работает,
`import flask` также работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается если убрать галочку Inherit global-site packages в pycharm при создании виртуального окружения и вручную прописать pip install flask, то всё заработает.'
Как я понял, эта функция использует глобальные модули, а не копирует их в виртуальное окружение.